# Bootstrap Carousel fails to slide

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the code I currently have, I'm not sure why the carousel isn't working. The previous/next buttons don't work and the slides wouldn't automatically slide. 
Used on Safari 7.0.6

```
    <!-- Carousel
```

============================================-->

```
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

          <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/Slide 1.jpg" alt="image">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Heading</h1>
              <p>Paragraph</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="http://pmilessyr.github.io/index.html">Link</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="img/Slide 2.jpg" alt="image">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Heading</h1>
              <p>Paragraph</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="img/Slide 3.jpg" alt="image">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Heading</h1>
              <p>Paragraph</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>


    </div>


<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/scale.fix.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where you're actually starting to 'spin' the carousel?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the error you are throwing. I tried out your code with putting in my cdns and images and it works fine. So your html for the carousel portion looks fine.

1. You are calling static libraries in your script sources so make sure those files are there or use the sites cdn.
   ex: http://jquery.com/download/

provide more information about the error you are throwing if you can.